# how to get lazy load effect to full page in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, user-interface

I am trying to get Lazy load effect to my website.

Here, My website is consisting a long page.. which has 5 sections.
Here, for user experience i need to load the sections when user scroll in my website then only i need to load those sections to my homepage.

**Note : In my Website all data is static.**

Is it possible.?

i know it is possible. I saw some websites like that.

But i have no idea to achieve this functionality.?

Suggest Better way to do this.?

Comment: *"But i have no idea to achieve this functionality.? Suggest Better way to do this.?"* - A bit of research, reverse-engineering and a coffee break.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer i did..
But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example when using `jQuery` you could use an onscroll handler like the following one.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

});
```

And this function then uses [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to determine the vertical scroll position and on defined offsets it makes AJAX requests to get the content.