# Lazy Loading An Entire Page Javascript Only

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load (which is when you wait until someone scrolls into view of an item to load it) an entire web page, not just images. It is a similar format to the instagram home where you scroll and it loads as you scroll or the same with facebook and pinterest. I only want it in javascript though. I don't have any clue on how to do it (all other methods I found were extremely complicated and I couldn't implement them) but in conclusion a simple lazy load (another example is [IFUNNY](http://ifunny.co)). Thanks!

Comment: *I don't have any clue on how to do it* Unfortunately we expect some sort of input on SO. Show some code that you've tried, the HTML that you start with and the HTML that you want to load; give us something to work with.

Comment: I'm not sure that instagram is performing a lazy load the way to describe.
IMO, they are just loading more images as you scroll, wich is more "infinite Scroll". This is done with a watcher on scroll position and an XHR query

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963306/how-to-get-lazy-load-effect-to-full-page-in-html

Answer (score 3):

- First listen to [pagescroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522807/scroll-event-listener-javascript)
- Second get [scrollbar position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)
- Third if scrollbar position >= 95% load data via [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: could you give some code as an example

Comment: Use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) and use the Information of the Links.

Comment: Im kindof a newbie but how do you use jquery like what is it